# Has anyone developed "health metrics" for tags on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'd like to understand whether a given tag is "healthy", eg:

- Is its use growing or falling?
- Percentage of questions in total, and over time
- Median time until answered
- Number and percent unanswered
- Number of unique users asking
- Number of unique users answering
- Distribution of answerers

Has anyone built something like this? Maybe with the API?

Comment: Most of that can be answered with SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: and isn't most of that info already [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/api/topusers)?

Comment: Thanks Rene! The SEDE is fascinating! I did not know about it. It might be a tool for building something that can answer these questions, but doesn't provide those answers out of the box.

Comment: Hm, I don't see answers to these questions in that list at tags/api/topusers. Can you clarify where you are seeing these questions answered there, maybe with a more specific link?

Comment: Percent unanswered is there.... as are the top 30 users for Q and A ... I give you it is a bit thin ...

Comment: You could go over some of the [SEDE questions on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsede%5D+tags+-%5Bbug%5D+is%3Aq) that are about tags.